# How do I bind all methods of a certain name in an Object into a template via the binding map?

Tags: java, groovy, binding, template-engine

A normal action in Groovy templates is to bind a named object into the scope of the template like this:

```
map.put("someObject",object)
template.bind(map)
```

Then, in the template I can reference and use 'someObject' like this:

```
someObject.helloWorld()
someObject.helloWorld("Hi Everyone!")
someObject.helloWorld("Hi", "Everyone!")
```

Inside the template, Groovy also allows me to define a method handle as a first-class variable in the template like this:

```
someObject = someObject.&helloWorld
```

Then, I can do these without referring to the object and method name:

```
 someObject() 
 someObject("Hello World")
 someObject("Hello", "World")
```

How can I bind the method reference like this at the 'template.bind(map)' stage along with auto-resolving all the parameter combinations like the '.&' operator in the script provides?

**Using a MethodClosure does not work — Here is a simple test and the error I get**

```
class TestMethodClass {
        public void test() {
            System.out.println("test()");
        }

        public void test(Object arg) {
            System.out.println("test( " + arg + " )");
        }

        public void test(Object arg1, Object arg2) {
            System.out.println("test( " + arg1 + ", " + arg2 + " )");
        }
    }

    String basic = "<%" +
        " def mc1=testInstance.&test;" +
        "println \"mc1 class ${mc1.getClass()}\";" +
        "println \"mc1 metaclass ${mc1.getMetaClass()}\";" +
        "println mc1.getClass();" +
        "mc1();" +
        "mc1('var1');" +
        "mc1('var1', 'var2');" +
        "testMethod();" +
        " %>";

    Map<Object, Object> bindings = new HashMap<>();
    bindings.put("testInstance", new TestMethodClass());
    bindings.put("testMethod", new MethodClosure(new TestMethodClass(), "test"));

    TemplateEngine engine = new GStringTemplateEngine();
    Template t = engine.createTemplate(basic);
    String result = t.make(bindings).toString();
```

**Error**

```
mc1 class class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure
mc1 metaclass org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.HandleMetaClass@6069db50[groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl@6069db50[class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure]]
class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure
test()
test( var1 )
test( var1, var2 )

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.lang.Binding.testMethod() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

**A user suggests I just use '.call(..)'**

```
"testMethod.call();" +
"testMethod.call(1);" +
"testMethod.call(1,2);" +
```

But that defeats the purpose. In that case I might as well just bind the object instead of 'testMethod' and use it normally in Groovy template with regular method calls. So that is not the solution here.

The solution will create a binding such that testMethod() can be called just like this, and resolved for all overloaded methods, just like the "mc1=testInstance.&test" provides.

**The mc1 is a MethodClosure and 'mc1=testInstance.&test' does some magic that I want to do that magic at the binding stage!**

The metaclass of mc1 is a 'HandleMetaClass'. I can also custom set the metaclass of the methodclosure from the Java side. I just want to know how to do that to get the same behaviour. The Groovy is doing that in the template (from Java side in the template interpreter) and so I want to do it the same, in advance.

Note that normally, the streaming template creates its own delegate already. When the template code 'def mc1=testInstance.&test;' is interpreted, the Groovy compiler/interpreter uses that delegate when creating the MethodClosure with a HandleMetaClass, and then installs that in the existing delegate.

The proper answer then **does not install a replacement delegate** as per @Dany answer below, **but instead works with the existing delegate and creates the correct objects to facilitate usage** of mc1 without the '.call' syntax.

Comment: I assume you've tried `map.put("someObject",object.&helloWorld)`

Comment: @tim_yates That works only within the script. I want to do the binding as already supplied in the map that is provided in template.bind(map). Ie. Need a way to make the correct Groovy object external to the script.

Comment: Do you have a simple, runnable example showing what you're trying?

Comment: @tim_yates are you familiar with templating with Groovy?

Comment: Yes, but I'm worried any example I come up with won't match the issue you're seeing...  Thats why a complete, simple, failing example would be cool :-)

Comment: def handle = someObject.&helloWorld will create a universal handle to the method and all overloaded signatures. Then you can do handle("whatever") instead of someObject.helloWorld("whatever"). But I want to do the '.&' definition from the Java side before calling the template. IE Not do "def foo=*bar.&method" in the template but pre-bind foo. Let me know if I'm still not describing it clearly.

Comment: Does http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/groovy-goodness-create-our-own-script.html get you close?

Comment: @tim_yates not related. It will probably involve making the object into a GroovyObject or Closure (Groovy) and then also assigning it a MethodClosure. I'm just not that versed at doing that from the java side of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your desired behavior by changing the [ResolveStrategy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#setResolveStrategy-int-) to [OWNER_FIRST](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#OWNER_FIRST). Since you want to access bounded closure directly (without . notation), you need to bind the closure method to the "owner" (template object itself) instead of supplying via bindings map (delegate).

Your modified example:

```
String basic = "<%" +
        " def mc1=testInstance.&test;" +
        "println \"mc1 class ${mc1.getClass()}\";" +
        "println \"mc1 metaclass ${mc1.getMetaClass()}\";" +
        "println mc1.getClass();" +
        "mc1();" +
        "mc1('var1');" +
        "mc1('var1', 'var2');" +
        "testMethod();" +
        "testMethod('var1');" +
        " %>";

TemplateEngine engine = new GStringTemplateEngine();

TestMethodClass instance = new TestMethodClass();

// Prepare binding map
Map<String, Object> bindings = new HashMap<>();
bindings.put("testInstance", instance);

Template t = engine.createTemplate(basic);

Closure<?> make = (Closure<?>) t.make(bindings); // cast as closure

int resolveStrategy = make.getResolveStrategy();
make.setResolveStrategy(Closure.OWNER_FIRST);

// set method closure which you want to invoke directly (without .
// notation). This is more or less same what you pass via binding map
// but too verbose. You can encapsulate this inside a nice static                 
// method
InvokerHelper.setProperty(
    make.getOwner(), "testMethod", new MethodClosure(instance, "test")
);

make.setResolveStrategy(resolveStrategy);
String result = make.toString();
```

Hoping, this meet your requirements.

Comment: Seems to work. I'll pass to my ultimate tests. BTW also works in your example if the resolve strategy us reset to  DELEGATE_FIRST after the call to InvokerHelper.setProperty.

Comment: All tests passed. Looks bomber! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This will work:

```
"<% " +
"def mc1=testInstance.&test;" +
"mc1();" +
"mc1('var1');" +
"mc1('var1', 'var2');" +
"testMethod.call();" +
"testMethod.call(1);" +
"testMethod.call(1,2);" +
" %>"
```

`testMethod.call(...)` works because it is translated to `getProperty('testMethod').invokeMethod('call', ...)`. The `testMethod` property is defined in the binding, and it is of `MethodClosure` type which has `call` method defined.

However `testMethod(...)` is translated to `invokeMethod('testMethod', ...)`. It fails because there is no `testMethod` method defined and you cannot define it via binding.

**EDIT**

`Main.java`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        String basic = "<%" +
                " def mc1=testInstance.&test;" +
                "mc1();" +
                "mc1('var1');" +
                "mc1('var1', 'var2');" +
                "testMethod();" +
                "testMethod(1);" +
                "testMethod(2,3);" +
                " %>";

        Map<Object, Object> bindings = new HashMap<>();
        bindings.put("testInstance", new TestMethodClass());
        bindings.put("testMethod", new MethodClosure(new TestMethodClass(), "test"));

        TemplateEngine engine = new GStringTemplateEngine();
        Template t = engine.createTemplate(basic);
        Closure make = (Closure) t.make();
        make.setDelegate(new MyDelegate(bindings));
        String result = make.toString();
    }
}
```

`MyDelegate.groovy`:

```
class MyDelegate extends Binding {

  MyDelegate(Map binding) {
    super(binding)
  }

  def invokeMethod(String name, Object args) {
    getProperty(name).call(args)
  }
}
```

Or `MyDelegate.java`:

```
public class MyDelegate extends Binding{

    public MyDelegate(Map binding) {
        super(binding);
    }

    public Object invokeMethod(String name, Object args) {
        return DefaultGroovyMethods.invokeMethod(getProperty(name), "call", args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133656/discussion-between-dany-and-saint-hill).

Answer (score 1):

`someObject.&helloWorld` is a MethodClosure instance and the code translates into `new MethodClosure(someObject, "helloWorld")` (MetodClosure is from the org.codehaus.groovy.runtime package). This way you can prepare the map in Java.

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work. I posted a test case in the original question above showing the error.

Answer (score 0):

It is the 'def' expression that has special semantics. Adding:

```
def testMethod = testMethod;
```

just before invoking testMethod() does the trick in your example.
I don't think you can achieve the same result with bindings alone.

EDIT: to clarify, since the testMethod object is not changed in any way when the def expression is evaluated, probably you cannot construct testMethod in such a way that it is automatically registered as a method by providing it as a binding. You might have more luck by playing with the template's metaclass.

```
Writable templateImpl = t.make(bindings);
MetaClass metaClass = ((Closure) templateImpl).getMetaClass();
```

Comment: Thanks for chiming in here. See skadya's answer above.